# Long equation spread across the whole page in two column format

Tags: latex

I use the strip environment for a long equation in a two-column page format, but the equation number appears at the edge of the first column and not after the equation ends.

```
\begin{strip}
\begin{equation}

f_{k+i,j} \left( 
\bar{A}^{k+i+1}\hat{x}_{-1} + 
 \bar{A}^{i+1}\bar{B}_k \begin{bmatrix} \Tilde{y}_0 \\ \vdots \\ \Tilde{y}_{k-1} \end{bmatrix} + 
   \bar{B}_{i+1} \left(
\begin{bmatrix} {y}_k \\ CA\hat{x}_k \\ \vdots \\ CA^i\hat{x}_k  \end{bmatrix} 
 +
\begin{bmatrix} M_s\delta_k \\ M_s\delta_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ M_s\delta_{k+i} \end{bmatrix} \right) \right) \leq  h_{k+i,j} 
 - \sqrt{f_{k+i,j}\Sigma_{\zeta_i}f_{k+i,j}^T}\Phi^{-1}\left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{s_{k+i}}\right)
 - \max_{\eta \in \Gamma} f_{k+i,j}\bar{A}^{k+i+1}\eta
\end{equation}
\end{strip}
```

[image: The output of the latex code]

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal example that replicates the current issue? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow the community to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly the issue you're experiencing. Can you do that?

Comment: Hey @Werner, I am writing a paper for a conference. It's one of the ACM (Association for Computing Machinery) conferences that uses its own class file name acmart.cls, I will see if I can generate a minimal exmaple